# Why to use {%url ....%} with slug?

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views, django-urls

I'm new in Django and making a simple blog to improve my skills. I couldn't understand the purpose of using {% url XXX %} with slug.More precisely;

```
<a href ="{% url 'theview' post.slug%}">
```

As i know, url tag above will map the link to view function named 'theview'. And also there is a regular expression filter on url.py to catch clicked link and match it to the appropriate view function. Then why we use {%url%} although there is a filter to notice if the link is slug or not? Isn't it enough to create link like;

```
<a href="{{post.slug}}">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We use `url` tag to generate uri with given names and arguments and keyword arguments. If you don't want to use then you need to manually write every url. That's a bad practice.

```
url(r'^blog/post/(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/$', name='post_detail')
```

If you have url like above then (Best way to it)

```
# post.slug = 'learn-python'
<a href="{% url 'post_detail' post.slug %}" > {{ post }}</a>
# is equivalent to
# /blog/post/learn-python/
```

otherwise we need to write like

```
<a href="/blog/post/{{post.slug}}/" > {{ post }}</a>
```

`<a href="{{post.slug}}">` will not work.

Comment: Oh,finally I got it. Thank you friend.